# how to convert a collection view to circular icarousel in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, icarousel

I want to show cells in collection view like in circular list, means that after the **last cell** of the collection view, on scrolling the collection view shows the **first cell** again, like **circular linklist**

I have tried using icrousel, but as icarosuel deals with views only, I don't want to finish the collection view completely and start again with icarousel, so is there any way I can make me collection view circular

this is my `collectionView` code

```
        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
         cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = 
                collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: 
                "CellName", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! CellName

        let gigModel = self.datasoruce?[indexPath.row]

        cell.lblTitle.text = gigModel?.title

        cell.btnPrice.setTitle(gigModel?.getPriceAccordingToGigType(), 
         for: .normal)

          cell.itemImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: 
          (gigModel?.getPhotoPath())!), placeholderImage: 
          UIImage.init(named: "place_holder"))

        cell.itemImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0

        if Utilities.isValidString(object: gigModel?.adminId as 
         AnyObject) {
            cell.btnStar.isHidden = false
        }
        else {
            cell.btnStar.isHidden = true
        }

        return cell
         }
```

and I want this to be circular list.

Comment: handle collectionView scroll, and replace elements of array your collectionView based on

Comment: I am having a little difficulty understanding this, can you please put a little more light on this. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried to create sample project and it was pretty simple, here is example code how you can implement "infinite" scroll

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    var array: [Any] = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return Int(Int16.max) // Int.max cause crash
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MyCell
        let correctIndex = indexPath.row >= array.count ? indexPath.row % array.count : indexPath.row
        cell.nameLabel.text = "\(array[correctIndex])"
        return cell
    }

}
```

Hope it will help you

Comment: Thanks for your concern, it is working now. Thanks.

Comment: @Alexandr Great Solution...! Its Working fine...! Thanks...!

Answer (score 1):

//Use Below code to get next cell.

```
func scrollToNextCell(){
    //get Collection View Instance
    let collectionView:UICollectionView;

    //get cell size
    let cellSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height);

    //get current content Offset of the Collection view
    let contentOffset = collectionView.contentOffset;

    //scroll to next cell
    collectionView.scrollRectToVisible(CGRectMake(contentOffset.x + cellSize.width, contentOffset.y, cellSize.width, cellSize.height), animated: true);

}
```